# Twine does not recognize --repository-url flag

Tags: python, setuptools, twine

I want to use twine to upload a project build to test.pypi.org. I am following the README for the basic use case from the [twine GitHub page](https://github.com/pypa/twine). I have installed the latest version of twine:

```
$ twine --version
twine version 1.5.0 (pkginfo: 1.2.1, requests: 2.9.1, setuptools: 20.7.0)`
```

But when I attempt to upload my project built, I get the following error:

```
$ twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*
usage: twine upload [-h] [-r REPOSITORY] [-s] [--sign-with SIGN_WITH]
                [-i IDENTITY] [-u USERNAME] [-p PASSWORD] [-c COMMENT]
                dist [dist ...]
twine upload: error: unrecognized arguments: --repository-url
```

This is the exact line of code referenced on the [Python Packaging Tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) and the Twine README, and --repository-url should be a valid flag. Is this an error with the argument passed to the flag instead of the flag itself, and if so what is it exactly that I need to fix?

My setup.py file for the project:

```
import setuptools

with open('README.md', 'r') as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name='MyPackageName',
    version='0.1.0',
    author='J. Chamness',
    author_email='myEmail@gmail.com',
    description='MyDescription',
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    url='https://test.pypi.org/legacy/',
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=(
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v3 (GPLv3)',
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using an old version of twine (1.5.0).  As [@phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd) [observes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51126774/twine-does-not-recognize-repository-url-flag#comment89238867_51126803), --repository-url was added to twine at version 1.8.  Upgrade to the latest version to get this functionality:

`pip install --upgrade twine`

Comment: `--repository-url` was added to twine at version 1.8: https://github.com/pypa/twine/blob/550bedb051ff10f259fe91ac0753358d4c767a89/docs/changelog.rst